# How to remove the Virtual Directory part in the links for my media files?

Tags: orchardcms

I have started a new orchard project and I uncheck Use IIS Express in my Orchard.web property's Web section and change the Project Url to http://localhost/TestOrchard, then I press Create Virtual Directory.

I uploaded some pictures in my Media folder and use it in my homepage.
 Everything seems ok when I view it locally.

But when I deploy it to my website, the link pointing to the media file becomes
 /TestOrchard/Media/Default/image/mypic.PNG
 Since the TestOrchard folder does not exist in the remote server, media files cannot be read and also the media tab on my Admin control panel shows nothing.
The correct url should be /Media/Default/image/mypic.PNG

How do I remove the unwanted TestOrchard/ folder shell?

Answer (score 0):

In the Admin/Settings, you can change your Base Url.

Comment: I did so, it doesn't change anything

Comment: I put my deploy URL to my Base Url